# R converting dates in different formats to a single format

Tags: r, date

I'm working with a dataset that looks like this -

```
data = data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                  Date=c('Jan 11, 2019 12:00:00 am','Feb 15, 2019 12:00:00 am','Mar 8, 2019 12:00:00 am',
                         'Apr 5, 2019 12:00:00 am','Apr 12, 2019 12:00:00 am','26/01/2015 00:00','2015-02-16 00:00:00',
                         '2015-02-12 00:00:00','2015-11-10 00:00:00','Dec 7, 2018 12:00:00 am'))

#Converting the Date column to character
data$Date=as.character(data$Date)
```

The column `Date` contains dates in different formats. I'd like to clean this column up so that all dates are in the **same format**.

The desired format - **YYYY-MM-DD**

HERE'S MY ATTEMPT -

I used the `AsDate` function from the `flipTime` package to convert my dates.

```
require(devtools)
install_github("Displayr/flipTime")
library(flipTime)

data$Date_New=AsDate(data$Date)
```

Which gives me the following error

> Error in handleParseFailure(deparse(substitute(x)), length(x),
>   on.parse.failure) :    Could not parse data$Date into a valid date in
>   any format.

However when I try the same function with any single date from my dataset, it works fine.

```
AsDate("Feb 15, 2018 12:00:00 AM")
[1] "2018-02-15"

AsDate("19/07/2017 00:00")
[1] "2017-07-19"
```

Any suggestions or alternative solutions would be highly appreciated

Comment: `lubridate::parse_date_time(data$Date, orders = c("%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")) ` would be an alternative, but I guess you are trying to fix the errors or you want to use flipTime without specifying the specific date format?

Comment: The `orders` argument could be written as: `orders = c("bdYHMSp", "YmdHMS", "dmYHM")`

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works well as an alternative. Please post it as an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: I used lubridate and it worked very well for a similar problem.  Here is a link to the various date symbols in r.  https://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html